# require_once results in "No such file or directory" error

Tags: php, composer-php, odoo, require-once, ripcord

I'm new to PHP.

Today I tried to require a PHP library called "Ripcord", and it's not working.

I installed the library using Composer, using this command:

```
% composer.phar require darkaonline/ripcord
```

...and as you can see the vendor library is created in my source tree:

[image: source tree]

Here is how I call require_once in my code (`test.php` in source tree above)

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$url = "http://ymb.lan:8069";
$db = "odoo_elite";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";

require_once('ripcord.php');

$common = Ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
$common->version();
```

But when I run, I get the following error on the require_once line:

```
% php test.php

Warning: require_once(ripcord.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/eylin/Dropbox/Code/elite-portal/test.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'ripcord.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/eylin/Dropbox/Code/elite-portal/test.php on line 10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If everything is in `vendor`, then the autoloader should take care of all of your require statements. You should be able to just put `use Ripcord\Providers\Laravel\Ripcord;` at the top of the class, remove your ripcord require and it should work.

Comment: Remove the `require` line and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Linux system, I support the file name you want to include is Ripcord.php (starts with uppercase R). However you are writing with small case r in the statement:

require_once('ripcord.php');

Try rechecking the OS type.